# What is the meaning of "as much as anything"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

**This book is mine as much as anything!**

What does this mean?

Does this mean, "This is REALLY MINE!!"

I would want native speakers' opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [idiom here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much+as+anything) can be correctly identified as '**as much as anything**', as you state.

It would only make sense in certain contexts:

_"Only the paintings and the silverware are yours."

_"This book is mine as much as anything!"

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "as much as" is used incorrectly in the example you listed.

> "As much as" is an idiom meaning "to the same degree as"

So saying "this book is mine as much as anything" is like saying "this book is mine, to the same degree that anything is mine", which isn't saying much.

A more appropriate use of the phrase would be to say "this book is mine as much as your book is yours."

Answer (score 0):

as much as anything
as much as anything (else)
no less than other things
You need to look at reliability and safety as much as anything when buying a car. It was war, as much as anything else, that made an artist out of Westermann.
*Answer copied from 'Free Dictionary' It's there online.

Comment: Answer rewritten below for clarity.

Comment: You should use the "edit" option if you want to make changes to your answer, instead of posting a whole new version of it.  (Especially one that's barely any different.  :-) )

Comment: Also, you should make it common practice to link the site where you got your info. You can do this by pasting the link, or hyperlinking a part of your text with the button that looks like a chain/link.

Answer (score 0):

> **as much as anything, as much as anything else:** no less than other things
>
> *You need to look at reliability and safety as much as anything when buying a car.*
> *It was war, as much as anything else, that made an artist out of Westermann.*

Answer copied from [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much+as+anything).